# Is a sub-shell the same thing as a child-shell

Tags: bash, shell, process, posix, subshell

There are this two names: a *subshell* and a *child-shell*.

Yes, a child process will be started by any of this:

```
sh -c 'echo "Hello"'
( echo "hello" )
echo "$(echo "hello")
echo "hello" | cat
```

Are all equivalent and share the same name? Do all share the same properties?

---

POSIX [has this definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12):

> A shell execution environment consists of ....

But the last paragraph of above link has this:

> A subshell environment shall be created as a duplicate of the shell environment, except that signal traps that are not being ignored shall be set to the default action.

And specially:

> Command substitution, commands that are grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous lists shall be executed in a subshell environment. Additionally, each command of a multi-command pipeline is in a subshell environment; ....

The `sh -c 'echo "Hello"'` is not included there, should that be called a subshell also?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A subshell **duplicates** the existing shell. It has the same variables¹, the same functions, the same options, etc. Under the hood, a subshell is created with the [`fork`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) system call²; the child process goes on to do what is expected of it while the parent waits (e.g., `$(…)`) or goes on with its life (e.g., `… &`) or otherwise does what is expected of it (e.g., `… | …`).

`sh -c …` does not create a subshell. It launches another program. That program happens to be a shell, but that's just a coincidence.  The program may even be a different shell (e.g., if you run `sh -c …` from bash, and `sh` is dash), i.e., a completely different program that just happens to have significant similarities in its behavior. Under the hood, launching an external command (`sh` or any other) calls the `fork` system call and then the [`execve`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(computing)) system call to *replace* the shell program in the subprocess by another program (here `sh`).

¹  <sub>Including `$$`, but excluding some shell-specific variables such as bash and mksh's `BASHPID`.</sub>
²  <sub>At least, that's the traditional and usual implementation. Shells can optimize the fork away if they can mimic the behavior otherwise. See [What is the exact difference between a "subshell" and a "child process"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421020/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-subshell-and-a-child-process)</sub>

Relevant man pages: [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

Comment: Thanks. What does running a bash script with bash shebang belong to?

Comment: @Tim Same thing as `sh -c`: that's a subprocess that coincidentally happens to be a shell.

Comment: (1) " launching an external command (sh or any other) calls the fork system call and then the execve system call to replace the shell program in the subprocess by another program (here sh)." Is it right that fork first creates a subshell and then execve replace the subshell with the external program? So in the two cases in your reply, a subshell is always created? (2) "A subshell that duplicates the existing shell." what does "that" mean?

Comment: (3) in `bash -c <command>`, after fork the shell and then execve `bash -c <command>` , a bash shell is created. Then are the system call used to run `<command>` again fork the bash shell and execve `<command>`?

Comment: @Gilles: So subshell is a child shell but not vice versa right?

Comment: @Gilles: Could you help with my question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261595/do-a-bash-script-and-bash-c-command-run-in-a-subshell-environment ? Thanks.

Comment: @cuonglm “Child shell” is not a technical term with a specific meaning, unlike “subshell”. If it's a shell that's a child, then it's a child shell, following the usual rules of English.

Answer (score 3):

A sub-shell environment does not need to live in a separate process, it just needs to duplicate the current execution environment. In `ksh93` this is done by a `virtual sub-shell` mechanism that does not call `fork()`. This makes ksh93 very fast on archaic platforms like `Win-DOS`, as `Win-DOS` is extremely slow with forking.

`sh -c cmd` on the other side creates a new process with the default shell that does not need to be the same as your current interactive shell.

Even when `sh` and your current shell are identical, this does not duplicate the execution environment and thus does not create a `sub-shell`.

Comment: So, in other shells except `ksh93`, subshell is a child shell right?

Comment: I know of no other implementation that implements virtual subshells today.