# What is the exact difference between a "subshell" and a "child process"?

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138467/265604) and [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), a subshell is started by using parenthesis `(…)`.

```
( echo "Hello" )
```

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/q/605808), [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1415441) and [this](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch10_10.html), a process is forked when the command is ended with a `&`

```
echo "Hello" &
```

The Posix specification use [the word `subshell` in this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html) but doesn't define it and, also, on the same page, [doesn't define "child process"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_08).

Both are using the kernel `fork()` function, correct?

**What is the exact difference then to call some forks a "sub-shell" and some other forks a "child process".**

Comment: Not clear why you are linking POSIX [Rationale: Base Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html) instead of the [Base Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) themselves: **3.93 Child Process** _"A new process created (by fork(), posix_spawn(), or ...) by a given process"_; **3.376 Subshell** _"A shell execution environment, distinguished from the main or current shell execution environment"_. So, not instances of the same kind of thing. Is this the distinction you are looking for?

Comment: @fra-san A `child process` could have a distinct environment than `main`: Like in `( LANG=C eval 'echo "$LANG"' )`. Is that child process (inside parenthesis) also a subshell (different environment)?

Comment: The expression in `( )` is [by definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) a subshell with its own execution environment. My point is that a subshell is not required to be implemented as a child process (as Stéphane points out in his answer with the ksh93 example). It looks like _subshell_ and _child process_ have not to be _both_ results of a `fork()` call; thus, looking for the difference between two kinds of fork doesn't seem the right point of view to me. That's why I was trying to better understand your question.

Comment: Ah, now I see that the [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) page you linked to actually says that a subshell _is_ a child process. In my opinion that definition is a possibly misleading simplification.

Answer (score 24):

In the POSIX terminology, a subshell environment is linked to the notion of [Shell Execution Environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12).

A subshell environment is a separate shell execution environment created as a duplicate of the parent environment. That execution environment includes things like opened files, umask, working directory, shell variables/functions/aliases...

Changes to that subshell environment do not affect the parent environment.

Traditionally in the Bourne shell or ksh88 on which the POSIX specification is based, that was done by forking a child process.

The areas where POSIX requires or allows command to run in a subshell environment are those where traditionally ksh88 forked a child shell process.

It doesn't however force implementations to use a child process for that.

A shell can choose instead to implement that separate execution environment any way they like.

For instance, ksh93 does it by saving the attributes of the parent execution environment and restoring them upon termination of the subshell environment in contexts where forking can be avoided (as an optimisation as forking is quite expensive on most systems).

For instance, in:

```
cd /foo; pwd
(cd /bar; pwd)
pwd
```

POSIX does require the `cd /bar` to run in a separate environment and that to output something like:

```
/foo
/bar
/foo
```

It doesn't require it to run in a separate process. For instance, if stdout becomes a broken pipe, `pwd` run in the subshell environment could very well have the SIGPIPE sent to the one and only shell process.

Most shells including `bash` will implement it by evaluating the code inside `(...)` in a child process (while the parent process waits for its termination), but ksh93 will  instead upon running the code inside `(...)`, all in the same process:

- remember it is in a subshell environment.
- upon `cd`, save the previous working directory (typically on a file descriptor opened with O_CLOEXEC), save the value of the OLDPWD, PWD variables and anything that `cd` might modify and then do the `chdir("/bar")`
- upon returning from the subshell, the current working directory is restored (with a `fchdir()` on that saved fd), and everything else that the subshell may have modified.

There are contexts where a child process can't be avoided. ksh93 doesn't fork in:

- `var=$(subshell)`
- `(subshell)`

But does in

- `{ subshell; } &`
- `{ subshell; } | other command`

That is, the cases where things have to run in separate processes so they can run concurrently.

ksh93 optimisations go further than that. For instance, while in

```
var=$(pwd)
```

most shells would fork a process, have the child run the `pwd` command with its stdout redirected to a pipe, `pwd` write the current working directory to that pipe, and the parent process read the result at the other end of the pipe, `ksh93` virtualises all that by neither requiring the fork nor the pipe. A fork and pipe would only be used for non-builtin commands.

Note that there are contexts other that subshells for which shells fork a child process. For instance, to run a command that is stored in a separate executable (and that is not a script intended for the same shell interpreter), a shell would have to fork a process to run that command in it as otherwise it wouldn't be able to run more commands after that command returns.

In:

```
/bin/echo "$((n += 1))"
```

That is not a subshell, the command will be evaluated in the current shell execution environment, the `n` variable of the current shell execution environment will be incremented, but the shell will fork a child process to execute that `/bin/echo` command in it with the expansion of `$((n += 1))` as argument.

Many shells implement an optimisation in that they don't fork a child process to run that external command if it's the last command of an inline script (`shell -c 'inline-script'`) or a subshell (for those subshells that are implemented as child processes).
(`bash` however only does it if that command is the only command of the subshell).

What that means is that, with those shells, if the last command in the subshell is an external command, the subshell doesn't not cause an extra process to be spawned. If you compare:

```
a=1; /bin/echo "$a"; a=2; /bin/echo "$a"
```

with

```
a=1; /bin/echo "$a"; (a=2; /bin/echo "$a")
```

there will be the same number of processes created, only in the second case, the second fork is done earlier so that the `a=2` is run in a subshell environment.

Comment: Why `{ subshell; } | other command` implies that the processes need to run concurrently but not necessarily `command | other command`? Indeed `{ ps; } | ps` or `ps | { ps; }` create an additional `bash` process compared to `ps | ps`. Especially intriguing since `{ list; }` is supposed to execute in the current process environment according to `man bash` or https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01...

Comment: Is it really because `{ command; } | other command` implies that the processes need to run concurrently that an additional shell process is started?... Isn't it rather that the creation of a new shell process is required here because `|` needs two processes to create a pipe AND because `{ ... }` must be interpreted by a shell, thereby requiring a new shell process to be spawned, whereas `other command` can be executed in its own non-shell child process? Yet, couldn't the pipe be simply created between the current shell executing `{ ... }` and the child process executing `other command`?

Comment: pipeline components run concurrently in different processes, that's not only for `{ ...; }` or other compound commands. Here I was comparing `{..} | ..` to `{...}` or `(...)` alone. In `bash` that needs to be a shell process that "runs" the compound command. In some other shells, you may find that the last command in a command group is executed in the same process as was evaluating  the command group, but that would just be an optimisation.

Answer (score 7):

Both (subshell and child shell) are a separate process than the parent shell (both are childs of the parent shell). That  is, they have diferent PIDs. And both start with a fork (copy) of the parent shell.

A subshell is a copy of the parent shell in which variables, functions, flags and everything is available as it was in the parent shell. Modifications of such values doesn￻'t affect the parent.

A child shell starts as a fork but it gets reset to the shell default values given by the start configs. It becomes a process used to execute some code (either a shell or a command).

A subshell could access variable values:

```
$ x=123; ( echo "$x")
123
```

A child shell could not (un-exported variables):

```
$ x=234; sh -c 'echo "x=$x"'
x=
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer but I'm surprised it doesn't mention child "process" at all.

Comment: @aderchox A child process is the same as a child shell in this context, child process or child shell does not get parent shell variables unless they're exported in parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

### Subshell

Child shell is also called subshell. Subshell can be created from parent shell and from another shell. Subshell can be created using:

**1. Process List**

A process list is command grouping enclosed in parenthesis. Example:

```
( pwd ; (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL))
```

This will print current working directory and number of spawned shell. **NOTE** Invoking subshell is expensive.

**2. Coprocess**

It spawns a subshell in background mode and executes a command within that subshell.

```
coproc sleep 10
```

If you type `jobs` command

```
[1]+  Running                 coproc COPROC sleep 10 &
```

you will see sleep as background process running in background.

### Forking a Child Process

A child process in computing is a process created by another process. Whenever an external command is executed, a child process is created. This action is termed forking.

```
$ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD  
umcr7     3647  3638  0 13:54 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
umcr7     3749  3647  0 13:59 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

As `ps -f` is external command (i.e. An external command, sometimes called a filesystem command, is a program that exists outside of the bash shell.) this will create child process with parent id of bash shell from which it is executed.