# Which of the following commands created a bash subshell

Tags: bash, shell, csh

> Which of the following commands created a bash subshell?
>
> 1. bash
> 2. bsh
> 3. csh
> 4. None of the above

This question asked in recent exam and i was unable to answer. Can any one give me right answer?

Comment: It is strange that they asked for `bsh` which is a shell created in 1984 as the first shell with integrated history editor and not commonly known.

Answer (score 1):

None of them (alternative 4).

A sub-shell is created in various situations, but the commands that you show creates child shells by starting a separate shell interpreter process (although I'm not sure what `bsh` is).

A sub-shell is, for example created inside `(...)`, as well as in `$(...)` (a command substitution), `<(...)` and `>(...)` (process substitution), and for the various stages of a pipeline.

What sets a sub-shell apart from a child shell process is that the parent shell's shell variables are available in it.  A shell started by running e.g. `bash` sets up a new environment, and only environment variables (exported variables) are inherited.

See also:

- [What is the exact difference between a "subshell" and a "child process"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421020/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-subshell-and-a-child-process)