# Example of subshell without child-shell process

Tags: bash, shell, process, subshell

I just recently learned that "subshell" is not the same as "child shell process" (see for example [What is the exact difference between a "subshell" and a "child process"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421020/136276) and the POSIX definitions of [subshell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_376) and [child process](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_93)).

To convince myself of this, I am looking for a command that illustrates (proves) that a subshell is created without a child-shell being spawned.

For now, everything I tried seemed to spawn a child-shell whenever a subshell is created:

```
$ echo $BASHPID; (pwd; cd ..; echo $BASHPID; pwd); pwd      # `( ...)` executed in a subshell
                                                            # and in a child-shell process

$ >&2 ps | ps       # Theoretically executed in two subshells and apparently without child-shells
                    # but I cannot be sure due to the outcome of the next example

$ $ >&2 echo $BASHPID | ps      # `ps` doesn't display a child-shell for the execution of `echo`
953790                          # but `echo $BASHPID` shows a new process that is necessarily
    PID TTY         TIME CMD    # a child-shell since echo is a built-in 
 948538 pts/2   00:00:00 bash
 953791 pts/2   00:00:00 ps
```

I am looking for a way to demonstrate that having a subshell doesn't necessarily imply having a child-shell...

**Bash 5.0.17**

Comment: In bash, a subshell is always a separate process. Not so in other shells like ksh93. So you're pretty much wasting your time if you're expecting an example for **Bash 5.0.17**.

Comment: In ksh93, here's a very simple example of subshell without subprocess: `a=3; (a=12); echo $a`. The reverse is also true: at least on Linux, one could implement multiple processes within a single subshell environment (i.e. `cd` could be an external command, running in a separate process, and still change the cwd of its parent). But AFAIK no mainstream shell is making use of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bash shell, subshells are implemented by forking a child process, so you won't see a case of a subshell not running in a child process in that shell.

ksh93 is the only shell that I know that skips the forking when possible for subshells (an optimisation that is still quite buggy and that the successive people that have tried to maintain it after AT&T disbanded the team that had written it have considered removing).

If you do for instance:

```
 strace ksh93 -c 'pwd; (cd /; umask 0; pwd; exit 2); pwd'
```

You'll see ksh93 not forking any process but do something like this instead:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_PATH)  = 3
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
[...]
```

Which saves the current directory on fd 10. Then:

```
chdir("/")                              = 0
umask(000)                              = 002
```

Which changes the current directory and umask in the subshell. And upon termination of the subshell (the `exit 2` not calling the `_exit()` system call):

```
fchdir(10)                              = 0
close(10)                               = 0
```

To restore the current working directory and:

```
umask(002)                              = 000
```

To restore the umask.

Some shells like FreeBSD's `sh` can skip the fork in very specific cases, like in:

```
var=$(printf %04d "$n")
```

(here with a `printf` builtin, and no change to the environment is being done in there).

In a pipeline, all components have to run concurrently, so they have to run in separate processes, even in ksh93.

In `bash`, they all run in child processes. In AT&T ksh or zsh, or with `bash -O lastpipe` (when non-interactive), the rightmost one doesn't (of course, you still need to fork a child process to run external commands such as `ps`).

You don't see an extra `bash` process in `ps >&2 | ps` or `(ps)` because `ps` is executed directly  in that child process, which before executing `ps` was bash interpreting the pipeline component: the subshell. For instance, in:

```
n=0; /bin/true "$((n=1))" | /bin/echo "$((n=2))"; echo "$n"
```

You'll see `2` and `0` in bash, and `2` and `2` in zsh/ksh93. `/bin/true` and `/bin/echo` are executed in child processes, `/bin/true` directly in the subshell process that had done `n=1` earlier, same in bash for `/bin/echo` (and `n=2`), but in `zsh`/`ksh`/`bash -O lastpipe`, the `n=2` was done in the main shell process, and a child only forked to execute that external utility, just like when you run `/bin/echo "$((n=2))"` not as part of a pipeline.

In `bash` (contrary to `zsh`/`ksh`), you do see an extra `bash` process in `(: anything; ps)`, the optimisation is only done if the subshell has only one external command, you'd need to use `exec` to do that optimisation by hand there: `(: anything; exec ps)`.

Same goes for `{ ps; } | cat`.

Comment: `echo "$$"` did you mean `echo "$n"`? In `bash -0 lastpipe` I still see `2` ad `0` (assuming `echo "$n"`), even when using `echo` instead of`/bin/echo`. But also in `man bash` it only says that "[with `lastpipe`] the last element of a pipeline **may** be run by the shell process", so it could also be expected to have the same outcome here even with `lastpipe`. The effect of `exec` is quite illustrative I find.

Comment: Yes, sorry, was meant to be `$n`. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misinterpreting "subshell" and "subprocess" (aka child process) and the bash man page doesn't really help much in clearing up the confusion.

A subshell is loosely what you get when the current shell calls `fork()`.  Fork creates subprocesses;  so the subshell *is* a subprocess.

The bash man page says that bash "executes commands in a subshell" but what isn't clear from this is that to run external processes (like `ps`), it then calls `exec()` in the subshell, replacing the running bash subshell with the new command's executable.  In some cases, like when `()` is used in bash, the subshell is started by `(` and exits at `)`, and commands in between may be started in their own subshells/subprocesses.

The only way that subshell and child process are not the same is that the child process may or may not (anymore) be another instance of the same executable.

Comment: I assumed the POSIX interpretation of [subshell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_376) ("*A shell execution environment, distinguished from the main or current shell execution environment.*") and [child process](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_93) ("*A new process created (by fork(), posix_spawn(), or posix_spawnp()) by a given process.*"). But if bash systematically ties one to the other, then indeed it makes little sense to try and distinguish them there.

Comment: From the ksh93 answer, I'd say the difference between subshell and child process is merely an implementation detail, and for nearly all shells, it isn't different.