# What are all the ways to create a subshell in bash?

Tags: bash, subshell

There are 2 main ways that I know of so far:

- **Explicitly**: wrapping parentheses around a list of commands
- **Implicitly**: every command in a pipeline

Are there more ways, either explicitly or implicitly, in which one creates subshells in bash?

Comment: Related, to understand what a subshell is and isn't: [Do parentheses really put the command in a subshell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man bash`:

- If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell 
  executes 
  the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait 
  for the command to finish,  and  the  return  status  is  0.
- A coprocess is a shell command preceded by the `coproc` reserved word.
  A coprocess is  executed  asynchronously in a subshell, as if the 
  command had been terminated  with the & control operator
- Shell builtin `complete` command: when called with the `-C command` 
  option, `command` is executed in a subshell environment, and 
  its  output  is used as the possible completions.
- Command  substitution,  commands grouped with parentheses, and 
  asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a 
  duplicate of the shell  environment

Comment: To complement more the list see [Is $() a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442704/383045)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by “subshell”. 
And you may be missing the point
in your “every command in a pipeline” bullet.

Any time you run ***any*** (external) program
(i.e., a script or binary executable, in contrast to a shell builtin),
unless you use `exec program`,
you run it in a sub-process (or processes). 
The shell forks and executes the program. 
`ls | wc` does not create a subshell any more than `ls` and `wc` do alone.

The interesting thing is that including it in a pipeline
can cause ***a shell builtin*** to run in a subshell. 
Consider this example:

```
$ read v
cat                                     # This is input typed by the user.

$ echo "$v"
cat

$ echo cougar | read v

$ echo "$v"
cat
```

The second `read v` command is run in a subshell
because it is part of the `echo cougar | read v` pipeline. 
Therefore, the value `cougar` is lost, and `$v` retains its first value.

Likewise, commands like

```
$ echo foo | cd /

$ cd / | cat

$ echo foo | exit

$ exit | cat
```

do not affect the main shell.