# Script function call: function vs $(function)

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, command-substitution

Taking how reference the following code for simplicity

```bash
#!/bin/bash

number=7

function doSomething() {
  number=8
}

doSomething
echo "$number"
```

It prints `8`.

But with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

number=7

function doSomething() {
  number=8
}

$(doSomething)
echo "$number"
```

It prints `7`.

I have the following questions:

- What are the *technical names* for each one?, I mean `functioncall` and `$(functioncall)`
- How does work each approach? It seems the former considers (affects) the variables outside of the function itself, the latter not
- When is mandatory use one approach over the other (it mostly about performance issues - of course - if there is any), if there are other reasons, they are welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are experiencing the subtleties of the Command Substitution.

The call

```
doSomething
```

is a simple function call. It executes the function, pretty much as if you had copy-and-pasted the commands of the function to the place where you call it. Hence, it overwrites the variable `number` with the new value `8`.

The call

```
$(doSomething)
```

on the other hand is a *command substitution*. It is meant to execute the function and *return whatever the function printed to* `stdout`. It is usually not used "standalone", but in variable assignments, e.g.,

```
os_type=$(uname)
```

That will execute the command `uname`, which on a Linux system would print `Linux` to the console, and store its result to the shell variable `os_type`. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to use a command substitution with a command or function that doesn't output anything, like your `doSomething`. Indeed, since the substitution `$(doSomething)` is basically a placeholder for the output of `doSomething`, the only reason why you don't get a script error there is that your function doesn't output anything. Had you stated, e.g.,

```
$(uname)
```

instead of

```
$(doSomething)
```

your shell would have tried to execute the command `Linux` and generated a

```
Linux: No such file or directory
```

error<sup>(1)</sup>.

The key point to understand the effect you observe is that in a command substitution, *the command is executed in a subshell*, i.e. any changes to variables made are not backpropagated to the shell where you execute the main script. Therefore, while internally it runs the commands of `doSomething` and sets a variable `number` to `8`, it does so in its own shell process that has nothing to do with the shell process that runs your script (save for the fact that its `stdout` is being retrieved), and therefore cannot modify the variable `number` you used in the main script.

For further reading, you may want to look at

- [What is command substitution in a shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440088/377345)
- [Is $() a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442692/377345)

here on this site, or

- [Greg's Wiki on Command Substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)
- [The Bash Manual on Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution)

for more overview.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> On the other hand, this means you can use a command substitution to execute a command whose name you do not know at the time of writing the script, but that you can find out by executing another command you do know.

Comment: Huge Thanks - for _command substitution_ is mandatory use `echo >&2 ...` within the functions called

Comment: @ManuelJordan If you want to catch error messages printed by the command, yes - you have to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: Yes, English is not my native speaking, my point was, if I have a function being called by _command substitution_ and the called function needs print any data (either informative or error) in the console,  so I need use `echo >&2 ...` - otherwise without `>&2` does not work