# pgrep process count show extra count

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've a scirpt name server.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
 
  process_count=$(ps aux | grep server.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l )
  echo "total process running:"
  echo $process_count

... other script code
```

when I run script I get output as

```
./server.sh
total process running:
2
```

Why do I get process count as 2 instead of 1? I only have one script running and have also excluded grep process. Even using pgrep -f server.sh and excluding pgrep gives 2 as process count.

Comment: `pgrep` would never return its own PID unless you ask it for the PIDs of processes called "pgrep" explicitly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $() a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442692)

Comment: Not sure but as far as I understand the answer, ps aux command creates a new subshell by forking a new process and this new process name is also server.sh and hence we get 2 as output.

Comment: Yes.  As the command substitution is more than a simple command, `bash` forks a copy of the shell to run it.

Answer (score 0):

0. if `ps | grep | grep -v grep` or `pgrep` are showing two processes then you have two matching processes running.   See for yourself by running the `ps ...` pipeline without piping into `wc -l`.
1. That's not `pgrep`, `pgrep` is a completely separate program from `ps`.  See `man pgrep` for details but, in short, run `pgrep -f server.sh | wc -l`
2. That's `ps` piped into `grep`, then `grep -v`, then `wc -l`.  This matches one of its own pipeline processes (the first `grep`) because `grep` is searching for "server.sh" which happens to be the command line argument for `grep server.sh`.
3. The usual method to avoid this (from the days before `pgrep` existed) is/was to `grep` for something that **won't** match its own command line, e.g. `grep [s]erver.sh` or `grep server\\.sh`, or just use awk:

   ```
   ps aux | awk '/[s]erver\.sh/ {count++}; END {print count}'
   ```

   or if you want to get the list of matching PIDs instead of the count:

   ```
   ps aux | awk '/[s]erver\.sh/ {print $1}'
   ```
4. Also, the `ps` in the Linux `procps` package has long supported a `-C cmdlist` option to do an exact match on the basename portion of process executable names.

   e.g. `ps -C apache2` will list apache2 processes even though `ps aux | grep [a]pache2` shows that the full process names are actually `/usr/sbin/apache2`.  This is not a regex match, it's an exact match on the basename - `ps -C apache` would not show `apache2` processes.

   From `man ps`:

> ```
>    -C cmdlist
> ```
>
> Select by command name.  This selects the processes whose
> executable name is given in `cmdlist`.
>
> NOTE: The command name is not the same as the command line.
> Previous versions of `procps` and the kernel truncated this
> command name to 15 characters. This limitation is no longer
> present in both. If you depended on matching only 15 characters,
> you may no longer get a match.