# Why doesn't sudo always spawn a shell sub-process?

Tags: bash, zsh, process, sudo, dash

I am trying to understand why some shells seem to receive a special treatment when called with *sudo*. For instance, there seem to be two possible behaviours:

The "implicit" group (*pstree* is a direct child of *sudo*, no shell in between):

```
$ sudo pstree -s $$
systemd───login───bash───sudo───pstree
$ sudo bash -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───login───bash───sudo───pstree
$ sudo zsh -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───login───bash───sudo───pstree
$ sudo dash -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───login───bash───sudo───pstree
```

The "explicit" group (the shell is a direct child of *sudo*):

```
$ sudo ksh -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───login───bash───sudo───ksh───pstree
$ sudo tcsh -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───login───bash───sudo───tcsh───pstree
$ sudo fish -c 'pstree -s $fish_pid'
systemd───login───bash───sudo───fish───pstree
```

There <strike>is obviously</strike> seem to be some kind of integration happening between *sudo* and some shells, but I could find no documentation on it. I also grepped the source code of both *sudo* and *bash* but could find no clue there either.

This other question seems related: [Why (...) doesn't spawn a new child process when run in background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430050/why-doesnt-spawn-a-new-child-process-when-run-in-background)

My versions of *sudo* and *bash* are:

```
$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.29
...
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

nope, that's not an interaction between your shell and sudo; it's that the shell tasked with executing replaces itself with the command you run!

You can remove sudo from the whole thing to the same result; for example, I run a zsh in an alacritty terminal:

```bash
$> bash -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───alacritty───zsh───pstree
```

no bash here!

We can verify that's what happens by running

```bash
$> strace -o /tmp/bash-pstree.strace bash -c 'pstree -s $$'
systemd───alacritty───zsh───pstree
$> bat /tmp/bash-pstree.strace # or just less /tmp/.... ; bat is just a nice code highlighter
```

There we see

```bash
$> grep execve /tmp/bash-pstree.strace
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "pstree -s $$"], 0x7ffc02c52d30 /* 102 vars */) = 0
execve("/usr/bin/pstree", ["pstree", "-s", "35735"], 0x55b90ec78d00 /* 102 vars */) =
```

So, the first execve is bash being called, the second one is bash replacing itself with pstree – there's literally no bash exisiting after that! No fork/clone happens in between.

Of course, that only works with the *last* command in a command chain. If we replaced ourselves with the command to be run earlier, we couldn't execute anything after. We can actually verify this pretty easily:

```bash
$> bash -c 'pstree -p -s $$; pstree -p -s $$'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
systemd(1)───alacritty(34604)───zsh(34609)───bash(39257)───pstree(39258)
systemd(1)───alacritty(34604)───zsh(34609)───pstree(39257)
```

See, here the first pstree is run actually in a process created by bash, the second by the same process, replacing bash.

Replacing the shell with  the program it runs is of course nice, resource-wise: we yield all the file handles memory, locks etc early on.

I don't know why some shells do that, and others don't (they probably use `fork` or `clone` to copy the own process, before `execve`'ing the command specified). Possibly, it's an optimization that never occurred to the developers (if you have a proudly rich shell like `fish`, why safe a couple of kB of RAM a bit earlier? Nobody will try to spawn 10000 fish from a shell script to run a command!), or it was software-architecturally awkward to introduce a special case, or it was impossible, because the shell maintains some control over the started process, and thus still needs to exist to be able to e.g. receive signals or do IPC. Of course, some shells are simply very old, and maybe a bit simplistic as a result (the last `ksh` release was 10 years ago!).

Comment: It explains a lot, thank you.

Comment: `strace -f -e clone,fork,execve bash -c 'pstree -s $$'` would be another way to verify that it doesn't fork before exec.  Your way is also solid proof, though: you're not using `strace -f` so it's *not* following into child processes, but you do still see an `execve`.  So it must have replaced itself.  You can also see that from `strace -f -e execve` (not displaying the `clone` system call that implements fork), just from looking at the PID number if there is a fork involved at all.  Tracing `clone` rules out the possibility you mentioned of forking but then replacing the original.

Comment: You can of course trace `bash -c 'pstree -s $$ && echo foo'` to make bash fork so it can run echo or not after collecting the exit status, as a way to test a tracing method to see how it looks when a shell does fork.

Comment: I believe that `ksh` was one of the more aggressive users of various kinds of optimization, such as tail-call optimization. [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) may have more to say about that if this draws his attention.