# How to calculate say output duration?

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, audio

My goal is to calculate how long it takes to output text to audio when using the `say` command.

For example, `say` will speak in real time:

```
$ say -v Alex "Hello there"
```

I can then combine `say` with `time` to answer the question in the text, although we have wait until the end of the actual audio output:

```
$ time say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?"

real    0m2.993s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.009s
```

1. Is there a way to calculate how long it will take to output any `say` command without actually executing it? How?
2. If not, how can I use `grep` to pull out the real line?

I'm trying something like this:

```
time say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?" | grep "^real   .*$"
```

But of course there is no result.

Is the output not being passed to `grep`, does `grep` not work for this multi-line output, or did I use the wrong pattern matching?

If `grep` won't work, what will?

#### UPDATE #1

Actually what I think I'm really looking for is the duration of the generated audio file that results from `say`.

Comment: Output it to an audio file and get its length?

Comment: Why not try something simpler, like `grep “real”`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I think this works for me.

Comment: @Peschke `grep "real"` didn't work for me so I tried something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Timing a run of `say`

> 1. Is there a way to calculate how long it will take to output any say command without actually executing it? How?

I see no way to accomplish this using any switches provided by the `say` command.

> 2. If not, how can I use grep to pull out the real line?

To parse the `time` output you can do the following:

```
$ ( time say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?" ) |& grep real
real    0m2.987s
```

Alternatively:

```
$ ( time say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?" ) 2>&1 | grep real
real    0m2.987s
```

In the above we've wrapped the `time ...` command in a subshell and then redirected the STDOUT & STDERROR (`|&`) to `grep`. The `2>&1` form does the same thing in situations where `|&` doesn't work for your particular version of Bash.

#### /dev/null

Incidentally, if you use the `-o <file>` argument to `say` you can speed up the translation of text to audio. Here since we don't actually want the audio file, we're directing to `/dev/null` instead:

```
$ ( time say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?" -o /dev/null ) |& grep real
real    0m0.310s
```

Alternatively:

```
$ ( time say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?" -o /dev/null ) 2>&1 | grep real
real    0m0.283s
```

Notice how much faster it is when not having to utilize the speakers to do this operation, that's the delay in using the audio I/O. By directing to a file instead it's much more efficient.

#### Calculating the audio's duration

To determine the duration of the resulting `say`'s audio file you can do the following:

```
$ say -v Alex "Hello there. How long will this take?" -o a.aiff && \
    ffmpeg -i a.aiff 2>&1 | grep Duration && rm a.aiff
  Duration: 00:00:02.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 364 kb/s
```

Here we can see that the duration of the resulting audio is 2.85 seconds.

#### Further improvements?

I looked into piping the output from `say` directly into `ffmpeg` but `say` apparently cannot do this. Others have come to the same conclusion per the Ask Q&A titled: [How to pipe output of 'say' to another command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56426/how-to-pipe-output-of-say-to-another-command).

#### References

- [Do parentheses really put the command in a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell)

Comment: The problem with outputting to `/dev/null` is that since we no longer have to wait for the audio to be output in real time we are welcome to generate it as quickly as possible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - that's true, I wasn't sure if the OP wanted the time it took for `say` to actually do the translation of text to speech and utter it, or just the time to do the translation.