# How can I get the pid of a subshell?

Tags: bash, process, subshell

How can I get the pid of a subshell?

For example:

```
$ echo $$
16808
```

This doesn't work, because the original shell expands `$$`:

```
$ ( echo $$ )
16808
```

Why does single quoting not work? After the original shell removes the single quote, does the subshell not expand `$$` in itself?

```
$ ( echo '$$' )
$$
```

Why does `eval` not work either? Is `eval` run by the subshell?  Why does it give me the original shell's PID?

```
$ ( eval echo '$$' )
16808
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest a reopen, because the questions are essentially different in my opinion ("how to avoid `$$` expansion" vs. "different pid in subshell").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to `bash`'s `$BASHPID`, you can do it portably with:

```
pid=$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')
```

Example:

```
(pid=$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"'); echo "$$ $pid")
```

You can make it into a function:

```
# usage getpid [varname]
getpid(){
    pid=$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')
    test "$1" && eval "$1=\$pid"
}
```

Notice that some shells (eg. `zsh` or `ksh93`) do NOT start a subprocess for each subshell created with `(...)`; in that case, `$pid` may be end up being the same as `$$`, which is just right, because that's the PID of the process `getpid` was called from.

Comment: Thanks. By portably, you mean ...?

Comment: Should work in any POSIX shell -- eg in debian's `/bin/sh` (`dash`) and in busybox (`ash`).

Comment: Is there no more direct way?

Comment: No. But please do not assume that a subshell is necessarily run in a subprocess -- that is not the case in `ksh93`, for instance.

Comment: do you mean your function will not work in ksh93?

Comment: It will work fine in ksh93 -- it will always return the pid of the process it was called from. It's the `(...)` from the example which may not spawn a separate process, as it does in `bash`.

Comment: Also, some shells like `zsh` or `yash` optimise out a `fork()` for the last command in a subshell. They may even optimise out the fork for the subshell if it's the last command in  a script so your `getpid` could even report the parent of `$$`. You could define `getpid` as: `getpid(){ sh -c 'echo "$PPID"'; return; }` to disable avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why you changed from function to command substitution (with exec)?  I am thinking about writing it into a  script, so whenever I want to know the pid of a shell, I just call  it ( or source it, whichever is better).

Comment: I wrote a script with content just `echo $PPID`. :) But your command substitution is good when I don't want to invoke a script.

Comment: I removed the old `getpid` function because it was pretty useless -- you could use it to display the pid fine, but if you tried to assign its output to a variable eg. with `(var=$(getpid); ...)`, it would've set `var` to the pid of the subshell created for the `$(...)` command expansion, instead of that of the process in which the `var=...` assignment was executed. I've added a better `getpid` function which will assign the pid to a variable instead of printing it.

Comment: I suppose `pid="${BASHPID:-$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')}"` would also work.

Comment: `(pid=$(sh -c 'echo "$PPID"'); echo "$$ $pid")` seems to work equally well without the `exec` in ash, dash and bash. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HaroldFischer all those shells optimize `$(cmd)` to `$(exec cmd)`. But I'm not sure that there's any standard guarantee for that -- better be explicit.

Comment: @HaroldFischer fwiw, an `ERR` trap + `set -E` seems to inhibit that optimization in bash: `(set -E; trap : ERR; pid=$(sh -c 'echo "$PPID"'); echo "$pid != $BASHPID")`

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for taking the time to reach out. Why is the `exec` necessary in the first place?

Comment: @mosvy Also, what is `test "$1"` supposed to do in `test "$1" && eval "$1=\$pid"`?

Comment: @HaroldFischer 1. without the `exec` or without that optimization, the `sh -c ...` process will be a grandchild, instead of a child of the process where a `$(...)` command substitution is used, and `$PPID` will be the pid of the `$(...)` subshell. That's exactly what happens in the `set -E` + `trap ERR` bash example above.

Comment: @HaroldFischer 2. `test "$1"` tests whether `$1` is an empty string or not -- a quick and dirty way to test whether that function was given a `varname` argument to assign the pid to or not; using a function was not the [brightest idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484442/how-can-i-get-the-pid-of-a-subshell/484464?noredirect=1#comment890014_484464) in the 1st place.

Answer (score 30):

```
$ echo $BASHPID
37152
$ ( echo $BASHPID )
18633
```

From the manual:

> `BASHPID`
>
> Expands to the process ID of the current bash process.  This
>                 differs from `$$` under certain circumstances, such as subshells
>                 that do not require bash to be re-initialized.

> `$`
>
> Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a `()` subshell, it
>                expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the
>                subshell.

Related:

- [Do parentheses really put the command in a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell), especially parts of [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/116858).

Comment: Thanks. (1) What does "re-initialized" mean? (2) Could you also consider why those ways I have tried do not work?

Comment: @Tim I believe this is answered by Gilles [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/116858). Bash simply does not update `$$` in subshells.

Comment: Do you mean I should always use $BASHPID in place of $$ in any case in bash? When shall I use which?

Comment: @Tim It depends on whether you, in a subshell, wants to get the process ID of the script or of the subshell. Both possibilities are provided and which is the  correct one is dependent on the application. No more specific answer can be given to that.

Comment: If I want to get the parent pid of a subshell, that is, the pid of the invoking shell of the subshell,  do I have to use $$? Can I use something else which is more predictable?

Comment: @Tim The PID of a parent shell of a subshell can't reliably be found unless you arrange to save `$BASHPID` in a variable and use that in the subshell.  There is `$PPID`, but that's the parent PID of the shell in the same sense that `$$` is the PID of the shell (it's not reset in a subshell). There is no `$BASHPPID` variable.

Comment: When is `$BASHPID` introduced? It isn’t available in my Debian machine with [Bash 5.0](https://packages.debian.org/buster/bash).

Comment: @FranklinYu `BASHPID` was introduced in release 4.0. You are either unknowingly running some other shell, or an older version of `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux a cross-shell solution (at least dash, bash, zsh) which does not spawn a new process is

```
read -r this_pid < /proc/self/stat; echo ${this_pid%% *}
```

At least in bash and zsh we can also use space as read-delimeter:

```
read -d ' ' this_pid < /proc/self/stat ; echo $this_pid
```

See also [man 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)  section /proc/[pid]/stat

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I guess that's a nice replacement for the first one (though it's probaly less performant than the second one).

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Then the opposite is likely true.

Comment: I just checked with strace (on Debian Buster with bash 5.0). Using your read yields three read-syscalls (at most 128 bytes at a time) read -d ' ' six (indeed one byte at a time). Dash on the other hand is *not cheating*. IFS=' ' read .. does read one byte at a time ...

Comment: great stuff. `read this_pid _rest < /proc/self/stat` could also be used (e.g. with dash). bash can do that 128-byte optimize then file is seekable (which is (kinda?) nice). that read syscall per byte is (in other cases) a bit "unfortunate"

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original "why" question - why doesn't `$$` expands to subshell pid, even lazily evaluated by `eval`?

Quoting [POSIX doc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

> $
>
> Expands to the decimal process ID of the invoked shell. In a subshell (see Shell Execution Environment ), '$' shall expand to the same value as that of the current shell.