# How to get caller function call method in bash

Tags: bash, subshell

Based on the following code below, is it possible to obtain the value of `$caller_method` from the pseudocode function below whether a function's caller has made a function call normally eg: `mytest 1` or using subshell style eg: `echo "(mytest 1)"`.

```
#!/bin/bash
function mytest() {

      # THIS IS PSEUDOCODE
      if $caller_method=directly; then
         echo "THIS WAS CALLED DIRECTLY"
         # Do other stuff
      elif $caller_method=inside_a_subshell; then
         echo "THIS WAS CALLED INSIDE A SUBSHELL"
         # Do other stuff
      fi
     # END OF PSEUDOCODE
}
    
    # CALLER 
    # Calling mytest directly
    mytest 1
    # Calling mytest inside a subshell
    echo "$(mytest 1)"
```

expected output:

```
THIS WAS CALLED DIRECTLY
THIS WAS CALLED INSIDE A SUBSHELL
```

So, does the mytest() function able to understand or store an information whether it has been called using this method `mytest 1` or `$(mytest 1)` ?

Also, I don't want to have any extra arguments passed from the caller function such as `$(mytest 1 call_inside_a_subshell)` or `mytest 1 call_directly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mytest() {
    # THIS IS PSEUDOCODE
    if [ $ORIGINALBASHPID -eq $BASHPID ]; then
        echo "THIS WAS CALLED DIRECTLY"
        # Do other stuff
    else
        echo "THIS WAS CALLED INSIDE A SUBSHELL"
        # Do other stuff
    fi
    # END OF PSEUDOCODE
}

# CALLER
ORIGINALBASHPID=$BASHPID
# Calling mytest directly
mytest 1
# Calling mytest inside a subshell
echo "$(mytest 1)"
```

It outputs:

```
THIS WAS CALLED DIRECTLY
THIS WAS CALLED INSIDE A SUBSHELL
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found out this issue is related how to detect if we are in a subshell using a built-in variable `$BASHPID` [How can I detect if I'm in a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524506/how-can-i-detect-if-im-in-a-subshell)

So the code can be written:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function mytest()
{
    if [ "$$" -eq "$BASHPID" ]; then
        echo "THIS WAS CALLED DIRECTLY"
    else
        echo "THIS WAS CALLED INSIDE A SUBSHELL"
    fi
}

# Calling mytest directly
mytest 1
# Calling mytest inside a subshell
echo "$(mytest 1)"
```