# How can I detect if I am in subshell, in bash and ZSH?

Tags: subshell

This question is different from [In Bash, how can I detect if I'm in a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/524506/3285) because it's not shell specific.

Let's say I open a terminal, which is `zsh`. I can go deep into that like this,

```shellsession
$ echo $$
359648
$ zsh
$ echo $$
359706
$ zsh
$ echo $$
359746
$ exit
$ echo $$
359706
$ exit
$ echo $$
359648
```

I want the first invocation of `zsh` to realize that we're already in `zsh` and to refuse the the creation of a subshell. Realizing that a shell is just a regular program and the notion of a "subshell" is just a basic abstraction when you so happen to spawn the same shell in a parent shell, is this even possible?

- Is it possible to detect when this condition *would* be reached?
- Is it possible to detect when this condition has already occured.

**This question is not specific to `zsh`**

Comment: You're not creating a subshell there, you're starting a whole another instance of zsh. A shell is just a regular program, but a subshell is not the same as just starting a new shell, but an independent execution environment that starts as a original environment. In particular, a subshell will see any shell variables set in the main shell, while a new instance of the shell will not.

Comment: if you want to prevent starting a new shell from e.g. an interactive shell, why not just define a function with the same name? e.g. `zsh() { echo sorry; }`

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this

```
thisshell=$(ps -o comm= -p $$)
if [ $(ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$)) == "$thisshell" ]
then
   echo subshell
else
   echo not subshell or different shell
fi
```

Comment: this seems to have nothing to do with detecting subshells

Comment: It detects if the current process is a subshell of the parent.

Comment: It appears to check if the parent process of the main shell process has the same name as the main shell process. A subshell process (if implemented by forking) and the main shell process likely do have the same name, but `$$` gives the PID of the main shell process, not that of the currently running subshell process.

Comment: If $$ doesn't give the current shell, then the answers to the previous question should work.  This case covers ones where those don't work.