# In subshell how do you get its process id?

Tags: bash, shell, process, posix

I know I can get process id of the main shell by `$$`, but how do you get PID of subshell created by e.g. `( ... )` from within the block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $BASHPID, to see the difference :

```
(echo $$ $BASHPID)
```

Comment: That seems to work in Bash, I also wonder, how can you do it in POSIX shell?

Comment: `(pid=$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"'); echo "$$ $pid")`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484464/40484