# Can I make cd be local to a function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell-builtin

Is it possible to make a function like

```
function doStuffAt {
    cd $1
    # do stuff
}
```

but make it so invoking that function doesn't actually change my pwd, it just changes it for duration of the function? I know I can save the pwd and set it back at the end, but I'm hoping there's a way to just make it happen locally and not have to worry about that.

Comment: Can't you just use `cd -` at the end of the function to switch back to the cached `$OLDPWD`? You don't need to explicitly save it yourself

Comment: @steeldriver `cd -` is a good idea, but if the script was sourced and terminated before `cd -`, the shell would be left in the path that was provided as an argument to the function.

Comment: You can use trap if you want to restore the start directory (but sourcing such scripts is a general bad idea)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes. Just make the function run its commands in a `( )` subshell instead of a `{ }` group command:

```bsh
doStuffAt() (
        cd -- "$1" || exit # the subshell if cd failed.
        # do stuff
)
```

The parentheses (`( )`) open a new subshell that will inherit the environment of its parent. The subshell will exit as soon as the commands running it it are done, returning you to the parent shell and the `cd` will only affect the subshell, therefore your PWD will remain unchanged.

Note that the subshell will also copy all shell variables, so you cannot pass information back from the subshell function to the main script via global variables.

For more on subshells, have a look at `man bash`:

> (list)
>
> list is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND
> EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin
> commands  that  affect
> the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.  The return status is the exit status of list.

Compare to:

> { list; }
>
> list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as  a  group  command.
> The  return  status  is  the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be recognized.  Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list by  whitespace  or  another  shell
> metacharacter.

Comment: @user414777 I stand very much corrected. I just tested and you're absolutely right, there's no need for the second `( )`. Sorry and thanks for teaching me!

Comment: Only `(…)` opens a subshell, `{…}` doesn't. What they have in common is that they're compound commands. Our reference question on the topic is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs/306141#306141

Comment: This works great, but with the caveat (maybe desired) that changes to variables will also be local.

Comment: +1, though I think your original version was more clear than the current version. Using `( ... )` *instead of* `{ ... ; }` for the function body is pretty subtle IMHO, and its impact is likely to be missed; whereas *adding* `( ... )` makes it very clear what's going on.

Comment: pushd and popd are implemented in bash as builtins so they don't fork like subshells.  cd and cd $OLDPWD also avoids forks, these do actually change the shells pwd for the duration of the function while subshells dont.

Answer (score 18):

It depends.

You can put the function in a [subshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping). (See also [Do parentheses really put the command in a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell/138498#138498.)) What happens in a subshell stays in a subshell. Changes that the function makes to variables, the current directory, to redirections, to traps, and so on, do not affect the calling code. The subshell inherits all these properties from its parent but there is no transfer in the other direction. `exit` in a subshell only exits the subshell, not the calling process. You can put a piece of code in a subshell by wrapping it in parentheses (line breaks and even whitespace before and after the parentheses are optional):

```
(
  set -e # to exit the subshell as soon as an error happens
  cd -- "$1"
  do stuff # in $1
)
do more stuff # in whatever directory was current before the '('
```

If you want to run the whole function in a subshell, you can use parentheses instead of braces to wrap the function's code.

```
doStuffAt () (
    set -e
    cd -- "$1"
    # do stuff
)
```

With the Korn-style function definition syntax, you need:

```
function doStuffAt { (
    set -e
    cd -- "$1"
    # do stuff
) }
```

The downside of a subshell is that nothing escapes it. If you need to change the current directory but then update some variables, you can't do that with a subshell. There are only two easy ways to retrieve information from a subshell. Like any other command, a subshell has an exit status, but this is an integer between 0 and 255 so it doesn't convey much information. You can use a [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) to produce some output: a command substitution is a subshell whose standard output (minus trailing newlines) is collected into a string. This lets you output one string.

```
data=$(
  set -e
  cd -- "$1"
  do stuff # in $1
)
# Now you're still in the original directory, and you have some data in $data
```

You can save the current directory into a variable, and restore it later.

```
set -e
old_cwd="$PWD"
cd -- "$1"
…
cd "$old_cwd"
```

However this is not very reliable. If the code exits between the two `cd` commands, it'll be in the wrong directory. If the old directory is moved in the meantime, the second `cd` will not return to the right place. It's possible to be in a directory that you have no permission to change into (because the script has less privileges than its caller), and in this case the second `cd` will fail. So you should not do this unless you're in a controlled environment where this can't happen (for example, to `cd` into and out of a temporary directory created by your script).

If you need to both change directory temporarily and affect the shell environment in some way (such as setting variables), you need to carefully split your scripts into parts that affect the shell environment and parts that change the current directory. The shell inherits limitations of early unix systems which didn't have a way to return to the previous directory. Modern unix systems do (you can “save” the current directory's file descriptor, and return to it with `fchdir()` in an exception handler), but there's no shell interface to this functionality.

Answer (score 12):

When descending into a directory "temporarily" to do some work — IOW, when you want to scope the directory change in some way — it makes sense to take advantage of the directory *stack* by using `pushd` and `popd`. It's a common technique in things like build scripts.

Say you're building a bunch of plugins.

```
for plugindir in plugin1 plugin2 plugin2 plugin4; do
  pushd -- "$plugindir"
  make
  popd
done
```

Comment: There are two caveats to this approach: It only works in some shells (POSIX `sh` does not have `pushd` or `popd`, and some other Bourne-style shells do not either), and it only works if you have a unified exit path (IOW, if you return from the function between the `pushd` and `popd`, you don't change back to your original directory).

Comment: `pushd`/`popd` are great, but they do echo the path to stdout. If that would clutter up the output, make sure to redirect each one to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @smitelli Good point, especially since (as the `bash(1)` man page says) "If the `pushd` command is successful, a `dirs` is performed as well." `dirs` will output the entire _stack_ to stdout. (Though, generally I come down on the side of a directory-change hardly being clutter. "Silent" `cd`s are teh ebil.)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That's true, which is why I'd typically do a `pushd` _before_ calling a function that needs to operate in that directory, and then the `popd` immediately after it returns. That won't work for all situations, of course, but I figure whenever I have a function that's complex enough to have multiple exit paths, I probably don't want it _also_ taking the initiative to go wandering around the directory tree on its own. Not if I can avoid it, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

[this answer is assuming **bash**; it won't work with other shells]

Using a subshell is simple and perfectly fine in most practical cases, except when your function has to modify variables in the main script.

For that case, you can use a `RETURN` trap to change back to the old current directory upon returning from the function. The `RETURN` trap is invoked no matter how your function is exited, and is not inherited by default by other functions.

```
doStuffAt(){
    cd -- "$1" || return
    local opwd=$OLDPWD
    trap 'cd "$opwd"' RETURN
    #
    # do stuff
    shift; "$@"
    # change some variable
    wasAt+=("$PWD")
}


% doStuffAt /
% pwd
/home/user
% doStuffAt /usr
% echo ${wasAt[@]}
/ /usr
```

But the old directory could've been renamed when you try to change back to it, and you will not be able to do it via its path. On **Linux**, you can emulate with `/dev/fd` in the shell the safer method of opening a file descriptor to `.` and then calling `fchdir` on it:

```
doStuffAt() {
    local fd
    command exec {fd}< . || return
    trap 'cd -P "/dev/fd/$fd"; exec {fd}<&-' RETURN; exec {fd}<.
    cd -- "$1" || return

    # do stuff
    shift; "$@"
    # change some variable
    wasAt+=("$PWD")
}
```

Here `{fd}<.` is used with a local variable instead of a fixed fd so that function be re-entrant.

Notice that `cd -P /dev/fd/X` will succeed even if the leading directories from its resolved path are not accessible. Simple example:

```
t=$(mktemp -d); mkdir -p $t/b/c; exec 7<$t/b/c; chmod -rwx $t
cd -P /dev/fd/7  # this will succeed
pwd
cd $(pwd)        # this will fail
```

Of course, the old cwd could be made itself inaccessible, instead of the dirs leading to it (by removing its `x` mode); but in that case, `fchdir(2)` wouldn't have helped either.

Also, there's still the case where the old cwd was *removed*. For that case, the trap could be changed to `cd "/dev/fd/$fd"; cd -P . 2>/dev/null` (the `-P` being mostly for cosmetical purposes). But it's not clear how changing back to an empty deleted directory would be useful at all.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks a lot for the fixes, but the last paragraph didn't seem right. see the changes (the "anonymous" edit was still mine) -- maybe I'm misunderstanding it?

Comment: `bash -c 'mkdir 1; cd 1; exec 3<.; cd ..; chmod 0 1; cd -P /dev/fd/3'` gives me a permission denied, but `bash -c 'mkdir -p 1/2/3; cd 1/2/3; exec 3<.; cd ../../..; chmod 0 1; cd -P /dev/fd/3'` does not (oddly enough).

Comment: Note that the only thing bash-specific in there is the `RETURN` trap. ksh93 and zsh use `EXIT` instead for that (not in sh mode in zsh, and you need to use the ksh-style function definition syntax in ksh93). So it should be easily adapted to those shells. In those you wouldn't need that double-cd workaround in your last paragraph, and you could give the `O_CLOEXEC` flag to that fd to avoid leaking it to other commands.

Comment: WRT your first example: it will not work in C / with fchdir(2) either. You cannot change the current dir to a dir to which you don't have search/execute permissions, no matter if it's via its path (with chdir(2)), or via an open fd (with fchdir(2)). That's what I was trying to say with "fchdir(2) wouldn't have helped either". But yes, that last part is a bit untidy / rambling.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected. I hadn't realised that. I had assumed using `fd = open("."); fchdir(fd)` was a reliable way to temporarily change the working directory. That's what ksh93 does to implement its non-forking subshells, and I see it fails at restoring the current working directory in `echo "$(chmod 0 .; cd / && pwd)"`.

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/141

Answer (score 1):

Invoke it in a subshell.

```
(doStuffAt some/path/)
```

Comment: That means you need to do this in every place where the function is used. The OP wants to make the function not change the pwd, this solution does work to leave the pwd unchanged, but only if you remember to code it that way. You may as well do `doStuff some/path; cd -`.

Comment: @terdon True, your solution looks better suited. I wonder how I failed to notice it! Just note that `cd -` is not a very good solution because if the script were terminated in between and had been sourced, OP would be left in `some/path`

Comment: Ah yes. Fair point.