# Sourcing a script to change pwd, ignore piping at end of command?

Tags: pipe, cd-command

I have a little script I wrote that lets me change to the directory of a script that's on the path, which helps me quickly get to other scripts I tend to want to edit, in the same folder as the original script.

I tend to do this by going one back in history, and prefixing that command, no matter what it was, like so

```
$ . cdbin my_super_script
```

This works most of the time - but - it doesn't work when the last command I was running was being piped somewhere,

e.g.

```
# if my last command was the following
$ my_super_script | grep -v bad | grep good

# then when I try and run my cdbin script using history, it looks like this
$ . cdbin my_super_script | grep -v bad | grep good
```

and then that just doesn't do anything - no errors, it just leaves me in my current directory.

Here's my simple `cdbin` script:

### cdbin

```
PROG=$(which "$1")
DIR=$(dirname "$PROG")
cd "$DIR"
```

EDIT: Note I am aware that I could simply type something like the following most of the time to avoid this, e.g. `$ . cdbin !:0` but find that a touch awkward to type :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this with a pipeline, [your `. cdbin` command runs in a subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/86440): so it changes directories in the subshell, and the effect is lost when the subshell closes.

To avoid this, since you’re only interested in the *command* you ran previously, use the history:

```
. cdbin !!:0
```

This will [extract the first word of the previous command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators), so in your scenario you’d end up with

```
. cdbin my_super_script
```

You can use `fc` instead to extract the previous command:

```
. cdbin $(fc -l -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

That can be turned into an alias to make it simpler to use, or made part of `cdbin` itself, for example if it’s invoked without any arguments:

```
CMD=${1:-$(fc -l -1 | awk '{print $2}')}
PROG=$(which "$CMD")
DIR=$(dirname "$PROG")

cd "$DIR" 

unset CMD PROG DIR
```